# How to remove AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Tags: asp.net

I have a url like http://www.foo.com/NewPage.aspx?pageid=10. However to some users this gets displayed as http://://www.foo.com/NewPage.aspx?pageid=10**&**

Now i read that the AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 gets appended as in my web.config since I have my web.config as `<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect"/>` whereas it should be `<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies"/>`

What I wanted to know is that is there an issue doing this change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045283/how-to-remove-aspxautodetectcookiesupport)

Answer (score 7):

Try `<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />`

for ref [remove AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045283/how-to-remove-aspxautodetectcookiesupport)

or use this in web config,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

Browsing through this issue i found in one article

> You could change your setting from
>   `cookieless="AutoDetect"` to
>   `cookieless="UseCookies"`. This will get
>   rid of it, but users without cookies
>   won't be able to pass session objects
>   around. Depending on how you are using
>   sessions, this may or may not matter.
>
> You could also write a routine that
>   sniffs search robots and rewrite the
>   Url, or write .browser files for the
>   search engines you are concerned
>   about.

For ref: [Remove cookie support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047151/remove-cookie-support)