# WebApi Post Methods always Returns "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." Status: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I Created a simple web api service to **GET & POST User Data**.

Every thing is well at Localhost. But when i host Service at server, Get Method is working fine when i call it from PostMan/Browser. But Post Methods always returns **"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." Status: 405 Method Not Allowed**.

One thing i got Confused here i.e I requested a POST Call, but status message shows me 'GET' error. Why it should be? If it is CORS problem? I tried CORS enable too with various scenarios/aspects by searching answers on internet at Application level(Web.Config as well Nuget Package Manager Cors). Still getting 405 Method Not Allowed. Below pasted my API Code:

**Controller NameSpaces:**

```
  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Http;
  using System.Web.Http;
  using System.Web.Http.Cors;
```

**Controller**

```
  public class UsersController : ApiController
  {
    [Route("api/Users/GetUsers/{UserId}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(int UserId)
    {
        try
        {
            List<User> userlist = new List<User>();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetUsers");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("aUserId", UserId);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dt = obj.GetData(out ErrorMsg, cmd);
            // Did Some Stuff and Returns Model;
            return userlist;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Written Error Log & Returns Empty Model;
        }
    }

    [Route("api/Users/SaveUser")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<User> SaveUser([FromBody]dynamic request)
    {
        try
        {
            string UserName = request.Param_Name;
            string Email = request.Param_Email;
            List<User> userlist = new List<User>();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UserSave");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("aUserName", UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmail", Email);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dt = obj.GetData(out ErrorMsg, cmd);
            UserAuthenticate userdata;
            // Did Some Stuff and returns UserModel;
            return userlist;
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            // Written Error Log & Returns Empty Model with Error Message;
        }
    }

    [Route("api/Users/SaveUserModel")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<User> SaveUserModel([FromBody]User request)
    {
        try
        {
            string Param_UserName = request._UserName;
            string Param_Email = request._Email;
            List<User> userlist = new List<User>();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UserSave");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("aUserName", Param_UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("aEmail", Param_Email );
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dt = obj.GetData(out ErrorMsg, cmd);
            UserAuthenticate userdata;
            // Did Some Stuff and returns UserModel;
            return userlist;
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            // Written Error Log & Returns Empty Model with Error Message;
        }
    }
 }
```

**Model**

```
public class User
{
    public int _UserID { get; set; }
    public string _Email { get; set; }
    public string _UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**Web.Config**

[Web.Config File Pasted here in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrYAA.png)

**WebApi.Config**

**Namespaces**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
```

**WebApiConfig Class**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
}
```

[PostMan Request & Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrlMC.png)

**Headers for Above PostMan Request**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Access-Control-Request-Headers →: *
Access-Control-Request-Method →: *
Allow →POST
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →72
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 16 Nov 2016 17:50:03 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
```

Thanks for any Helps!! Got Wasted a Day for this error.

Comment: how are you calling this API? and which method?

Comment: Through Post Man I'm calling. Method is SaveUser & SaveUserModel. Attached PostMan Request & Response Image. As Well Pasted Headers

Comment: Are you sure? you are selecting POST?

Comment: @viveknuna Yeah! i'm sure

Comment: and what url are u hitting ?

Comment: @viveknuna have a look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrlMC.png

Comment: http://url.com/api/Users/SaveUser

url.com is dummy domain which i gave to understand u the problem.

Comment: _UserID=abc&_Email =xyz&_UserName=pqr
You have to make sure that the HTTP header contains

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Call SaveUser with these things, surely it will work

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: @viveknuna I tried as you suggested and below are the header

POST /api/Users/SaveUser HTTP/1.1

Host: XXXXX

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Cache-Control: no-cache

Postman-Token: ef327cf8-a300-6528-0157-accced4ee3b9

Param_Name=120&Param_Email=MyName 

but still not solved

Comment: then what happened ?

Comment: Same error Message with 405 Status

Comment: I'm sorry, you have to call SaveUserModel with these parameters. then We will try to solve for SaveUser

Comment: I tried with SaveUserModel with same parameters, still getting same error

Comment: You class variable isUserName or _UserName

Comment: In model i'm having _UserName, i already got compilation error at SaveUserModel method coz of i'm given UserName. Changed to _UserName. Still problem exist

Comment: First fix that problem . try to keep the member name same across application  and pass the same name in Post request

Comment: Already Fixed, and tried SaveUserModel post call again. Error as it is 405

Comment: That user input model, there's no requirement to have 'param_' in the body of your request in Postman. The model binding will match the model if you specify  the object correctly. just use the Json notation. I would suggest commenting out all other api calls for that controller... just to see if its another Route that is conflicting.. if it starts working, uncomment one at a time to see where the issue lies.

Comment: why are you using dynamic objects in the requests?

Comment: @Derek Hi, FYI.

Yes at earlier stage of api development, i developed api with only model which is working fine at local level. when i moved api to server level its getting 405 error. so, i preferred alternate api with dynamic objects which dynamic objects also supports API post calls  with 4.5 framework.

Comment: as well no other controller nor route is there among solution (as of my knowledge i think if another route conflicts happen it won't return 405 error).

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem? I'm having the same issue and currently have no ideas on what's wrong...

Comment: At last, Problem Solved. Its Because of something missed in requested url. i.e "www".
To Make Post call success, we need to append www in url like below
"http: //www.url.com/api/User/SaveUser".
But, i'm always trying without www which always get 405 Error

Comment: @Prokurors Problem is solved, Just Add, WWW in URL at post calls. Then  your problem will resolved.

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old post but, for anyone else looking for a solution to this problem. I had this issue and realized that I was posting to my webapi using http but IIS was redirecting my request to https. This redirect was causing postman to change the POST to a GET. changing my URL to https fixed the problem for me.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the http vs https. i have the same prob

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks so much. I spent way too much time trying to figure this one out.

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me insane!

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution of your problem

[ASP.NET WebApi : (405) Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065385/asp-net-webapi-405-method-not-allowed?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Finally I changed the cookieless="AutoDetect" in web.config to cookieless="UseCookies" and the problem solved.

Comment: If I can I will give you 500 points. It's save my entire day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not Enabled CORS decorate your controller as below.

```
  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")]
```

Also put belo code in webapiconfig.cs file

```
  config.EnableCors();
```

If you are hosting your endpoints in public api then 
decorate controller as below.

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/users")]
    public class usersController : ApiController
```

Then Get for example,

```
   //Get http:192.168.0.0:2210/api/users/
      [Route("~/api/users")]

     //POST  http:192.168.0.0:2210/api/users/
     [Route("~/api/users")] 

    //Get on id
     //POST  http:192.168.0.0:2210/api/users/
     [Route("~/api/users/{id}")]
```