# ASP.Net WepAPI - I can get results from Get Methods but I cannot Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

My API contains 2 Get methods and 1 POST. The 2 Gets work however the POST returns this messgae:

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

These are my methods:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<tblMetrHist> Get(string accntnum)
    {
        ...
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<CustomerInfo> GetCustomer(string accntnum)
    {
        ...
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri] string num, [FromUri] string reading)
    {
        using (CustomerEntities entities = new CustomerEntities())
        {
            entities.tbl1.Add(new tbl1()
            {
                Number = num,
                Reading = reading
            });

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

And my Route is simply:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
```

So I'm not sure how to make the API recognize the method as a "Post" and not a "Get". Help please?

Comment: What url you were using for get and for post? And what version MVC you are using?

Comment: Are you posting your data using HTTP url or HTTPS url ? Try below links.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640317/webapi-post-methods-always-returns-the-requested-resource-does-not-support-http

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065385/asp-net-webapi-405-method-not-allowed?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Serge MVC is: newVersion="5.2.7.0" as for the urls they are https..api/Data/Get?num={num}, https..api/Data/GetCustomer?num={num}, and https..api/Data/Post?num={num}&reading={reading}. Like I said the two Gets work but not the Post, it gives me the message I put in my OP

Comment: @ChinmayT always in https

Comment: @KristinVernon Thanks, did you try my code?With your urls post should work now. pls let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public string Num {get; set;}
 public string Reading {get; set;}
}
```

and try this

```
[HttpPost()]
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri] ViewModel model)
  {
       var num=model.Num;
        .....
}
```

UPDATE

Since the browser automatically performs a get call, I recommended PO to use another tool to post.  "Advanced Rest Client" of Chrome was selected by PO to make a post and everytning worked properly.

Comment: I tried this and I still get the error: {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

Comment: @KristinVernon How do you call  the Post method? Do you use application or Postman? Can you post some code pls?

Comment: I debug the API from VisualStudio and I'm simply using the url to make the Post call

Comment: What code you use to make a post  call? by default from browser it will be get call

Comment: I'm only using the browser, because I currently have it running on localhost.

Comment: Ah you were right from the browser it automatically performed a get call so I used a "Advanced Rest Client" in chrome and from there I was able to make the post. Thanks!