# 405 method not found error when web api call from device

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

405 method not found error comes when i call web API from my xamarin mobile application on device or emulator.

web api runs successfully when i call from postmen.

This error comes for only POST Method.

anybody have idea?

please suggest.

EDIT:

```
public async Task Request(string url, string contents, HttpMethod methodType, string mediaStream = "application/json", bool isTokenNeeded = true)
{
    bool isSuccessRequest = true;
    string responseBodyAsText;

    try
    {
        if (!Utility.IsServiceAvailable)
        {
            OnError?.Invoke(new ErrorData
            {
                ErrorText = SystemMessages.OfflineServer
            });
            return;
        }

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(methodType, url);

            if (methodType == HttpMethod.Post)
            {
                message.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
                message.Content = new StringContent(contents);
                // message.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contents.Length;
                message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaStream);
            }

            // Add accesstoken to request header
            if (isTokenNeeded)
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + ApplicationConfiguration.Token.AccessToken);

            httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0, 0);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                var error = new ErrorData() { ErrorText = SystemMessages.OfflineServer };
                OnError?.Invoke(error);
                return;
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorData>(responseBodyAsText);
                OnError?.Invoke(error);
                return;
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorData>(responseBodyAsText);
                OnError?.Invoke(error);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException hre)
    {
        responseBodyAsText = "Exception : " + hre.Message;
        isSuccessRequest = false;
        OnError?.Invoke(new ErrorData
        {
            ErrorText = hre.Message
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        responseBodyAsText = "Exception : " + ex.Message;
        isSuccessRequest = false;
        OnError?.Invoke(new ErrorData
        {
            ErrorText = ex.Message
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any bit of your code.

Comment: @PaulKertscher please check my edit.

Comment: downvoter care to  explain please :|

Comment: Some things to ckeck: Are the URL and the data correct? If auth is needed: Is there a valid access token? Are you passing the access token correctly? Is the method correct?

Comment: yes.URL and Data are correct.ii cheked with same data and url in postmen.authentication is not needed in this call.so no need to pass tocken here.

Comment: I did downvote since I think that this is not a very well posed question. With the code added it's starting to get better, but you should really strip it down to an [mcve]. And the caller site would be great to see, too.

Comment: ok.but i thought this error is regarding some authentication setting from web service ..thats y didnt feel to post code  necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET WebApi : (405) Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065385/asp-net-webapi-405-method-not-allowed)

Answer (score 3):

I changed the `cookieless="AutoDetect"` in `web.config` to `cookieless="UseCookies"` and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

405 is a server response that informs you, that the method (`POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, ...) is not supported by the target resource

> The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource

([Source](https://httpstatuses.com/405))

If your web API is configured correctly I suppose that you've called the API with the wrong method, e.g. `POST` when it should've been a `GET` or other way round.

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati - 405 is a server response. You can't tell me that your request was exactly the same, but still your server responded differently.

Comment: yes.its is actlay.. 1 more thing i would like to mentios. that this web service is hosted in local iis.